# How to reset the states of (UNDO & REDO) button on froala editor

Tags: jquery, html, editor, undo-redo, froala

Hi i am using froala editor to save html for each stages ..

consider there are three stages.. A,B and C ..

Froala editor is only one

```
$('#txt_blog_editor').editable({
});
```

The div is same for all the three stages as stages can be created dynamically .. i have an issue here with the **REDO** and **UNDO** buttons..

Example

On click of Stage A and i type `"This is stage A"`

then i press stage B

The div is cleared and then i type `"This is Stage B"`

here when i press undo button the text changes to "This is Stage A". I want to clear **`redo undo`** history/cache/buffer and also `CTRL + Z` on click of the stages .

Is there any direct method in froala to destroy the history or reset the state of Redo & Undo buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to clear the undoStack.

```
$(your_selector).data('fa.editable').undoStack = [];
$(your_selector).data('fa.editable').undoIndex = [];
$(your_selector).data('fa.editable').saveUndoStep();
```

Or simpler:

```
$(your_selector).editable('initUndoRedo');
```

Comment: is there anything like this to clear redo stack as well?

Comment: my redo is not working as expected .. infact nothing happens when froala redo is pressed

Answer (score 1):

Froala Editor 3.0 has an `.undo.reset()` method that resets Froalas undo-redo state to `init`, (cleared out). The `"$(your_selector).editable('initUndoRedo')"`
that is mentioned in the accepted answer is no longer available as far as I can tell.